# Stripe API - Next Payment date

Tags: stripe-payments

I am signing my customers to a monthly recurring billing using the stripe API.

How can I display when their next payment is due given this respone:

```
"subscription": {
    "current_period_end": 1306060846,
    "status": "trialing",
    "plan": {
      "interval": "month",
      "amount": 1000,
      "trial_period_days": 0,
      "object": "plan",
      "id": "Basic"
    },
    "current_period_start": 1305974416,
    "start": 1305974416,
    "object": "subscription",
    "trial_start": 1305974416,
    "trial_end": 1306060846,
    "customer": "O8ygDbcWW9aswmxctU9z",
  },
  "id": "O8ygDbcWW9aswmxctU9z"
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
trial_end gives the next_payment_date in timestamp.
```

You can transfer it into date format using date function in php.

**Update:** As of mid 2019, for a subscription not currently in trial, you'll find the Unix timestamp for the next billing period in the `Subscription` object as `current_period_end`.

Comment: Eh, is this correct? It's an old post, so maybe it once was right, but it doesn't seem right. Sounds more likely that `current_period_end` (a timestamp) is more likely to do it

Comment: Agreed @rtf, currently its `current_period_end`

Comment: Is this timestamp UTC?

Comment: so its `current_period_end` then? ok ok this answer should be updated

Answer (score 9):

```
$timestamp = "2306060846";
$next_payment_date = date('Y-m-d',$timestamp));
```

It gives you time in Y-m-d format

Comment: how can I expand my answer

Answer (score 5):

You can check the status of the subscription as follows:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_7G9REJXtaW05QY")
subscription = customer.subscriptions.retrieve("sub_7HFIqkWIDqEhho")

if subscription.status == 'trialing'
  next_payment_date = Time.at(subscription.trial_end).strftime("%B %d, %Y")
end
```

After the trail ends you can check the `current_period_end` attribute from the subscription

```
next_payment_date = Time.at(subscription.current_period_end).strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

Moreover, you can use the `current_period_end` if you have only one month trial. That would work in all the cases.

> PS: For the status check, the word is `trialing` and not `trialling`, if I am not wrong, there is a spelling mistake by Stripe team. :-)

Comment: It's not a spelling mistake, it's US English.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not fully possible. `trial_end` (if set) will be the first payment date.  `current_period_end` will be the next charge *attempt*, but if there is a decline, the next charges will follow the schedule in the settings (e.g. retry after 1 day, retry after 3 days, cancel).  You must track declines and to calculate the next payment date using the rules from the settings.